# Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading .emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, startup

When I start Emacs, I get the following error message and was wondering how I can fix it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zRjU.png)

When I then start emacs with --debug-init as recommended, it shows the following error log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSNiI.png)

Since it might have something to do with my .emacs file, here is the code for it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKCAB.png)

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: When you start emacs with --debug-init, the message shows an error "Reading at buffer position 1471". What happens if you click on the link "buffer position 1471" ?

Comment: Please don't use images unless they are necessary to show the problem.  Here, you are showing just text: error messages and code. You can cut-and-paste text into your question between triple backticks to mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

exec-path-from-shell is a package that needs to be installed. When you say require exec-path-from-shell, you are telling emacs to load this package. However, this is not installed so it complains. You can either comment out that line or if you'd like to install it, follow instructions here:
https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell